# Had to print special characters Û and ß, yet they are constantly being printed on console as white squares

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, render

I'm using Visual Studio.

The code just gives this weird output:

```
████   ███  █   ▄  █▄█▄
█▄█▄█▄

 ▀  ▀
```

Is there any reason for this? If there's some logic behind this and its not just a glitch, then I think I might be able to use it to render like, images and characters?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
int main() {
    printf("ÛÛÛÛ   ÛÛÛ  Û\tÜ  ÛÜÛÜ \nÛÜÛÜÛÜ \n");
    printf("\n ß  ß "); 
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your console is using a different character set from your compiler. The good news is that you can change the character set of the console. On Windows this is done with the `SetConsoleOutputCP` function.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850#Character_set

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest that you could set the character set of the compiler to be consistent with the console.

First, you need to check the character set of the console. Open the console, right click the console, and select `Properties`.
[image]

[image]

You will see the Current code page is `65001(UTF-8)`.

Then, you could select `Tools->Customize->Commands->Add Command..->File->Advanced Save Options` in VS. And you could set the character set in `File->Advanced Save Options`.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Standard console I/O on Windows uses 8-bit characters interpreted through a code page to decide which characters to display.  Especially disturbing is the fact that the default code page is one used by DOS [code page 437](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_437) or [code page 850](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_850), despite most editors using a different code page such as [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252).  So incompatibility is almost guaranteed.

The way around this is to bypass the standard C and C++ output entirely, and call the Windows API console functions directly with wide-character (UTF-16) Unicode strings directly.  If you've configured your console with a font that supports all the characters you require, this will allow you to display anything regardless of what code page is configured.

[`GetStdHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getstdhandle) will give you the handle you need to pass to [`WriteConsoleW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole) to output the string.

```
#include <windows.h>
int main() {
    HANDLE hConsoleOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);  // checking of return value for errors skipped for brevity
    PCWSTR str1 = L"ÛÛÛÛ   ÛÛÛ  Û\tÜ  ÛÜÛÜ \nÛÜÛÜÛÜ \n";
    DWORD dwWritten = 0;
    WriteConsoleW(hConsoleOut, str1, _wcslen(str1), &dwWritten, NULL);
    PCWSTR str2 = L"\n ß  ß "; 
    WriteConsoleW(hConsoleOut, str2, _wcslen(str2), &dwWritten, NULL);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```